# How to convert NSView to NSTableView in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSTableView that has multiple objects of a custom NSTableViewCell.
Each NSTableViewCell object has three NSTextFields.
I want to send the inputed text in each of the NSFields and assign it to a String variable.
The problem is that I need to get the superview object in order to determine the selectedRow in which that custom NSTableViewCell exists.

something would maybe look like this in Swift:

```
let textField = sender as! NStextField
let myView = textField.superview?.superview?.superview as! NSTableView
let num = myView.row(for: textField.superview!)
```

I tried this for one of the NSTextField:

```
- (IBAction)setValue:(id)sender {
    NSTableView *thisTable = self.cell.superview.superview.superview.superview;
    NSInteger num = [thisTable selectedRow];  
}
```

It didn't work and also I'm getting this warning:

> Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSTableView *' with an
>   expression of type 'NSView * _Nullable'

My CustomCell class is a simple Class just to draw the cell.

```
@implementation CustomCell
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if(self != nil) {
        _cellTitle;
        _cellBackLight;
        _cellTime;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect { 
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

The .h file:

```
@interface CustomCell : NSTableCellView
@property NSString *cellTitle;
@property double cellValue;
@property int cellTime;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *titleField;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *valueField;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *durationField; 
//All outlets are linked from Storyboard to the CustomCell class.
@end
```

The tableView delegate:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)viewTableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    NSTableCellView *cell = [viewTableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

    cell = [viewTableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MainCell" owner:self];
    return cell;
}
```

---

What I am trying to achieve : 
[image]

Comment: Why dont you register the NSTableView as an `IBOutlet` directly so you dont have to call `superview.superview....` ?

Comment: Also take a look of your hierarchy, it seems that `textField.superview?.superview?.superview ` is not your NSTableView

Comment: Because you can create and add unlimited number of custom cells in my table, so creating an outlet out of each of the text field won't help because it won't know in which row it exists.

Comment: I suggested to register the `NSTableView` as an outlet, not the textfields. 
e.g. `IBoutlet myTableView: NSTableView!` then you do `num = myTableView.row(for: textField.superview!)
 `

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but how would that work if I have multiple custom cells with three text fields in each of them? if you have an answer that works please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: first you should post more code, such as your custom cell code, and nstableview delegate implementation for instance

Comment: I did it, I hope it helps

Comment: did you implement `NSTextFieldDelegate` ?

Comment: No, and I am not sure how to do so. I am new to Cocoa. I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194563/discussion-between-olympiloutre-and-fady-e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally forgot the syntax of `Objective C` but here is how you can achieve this in `Swift` for iOS.

**Disclaimer :** I am well aware that there are many differences between iOS and MacOS development, however this is a showcase on "how to organise your code to achieve this specific task". Even if it is not copy/pastable, not even tested, the method employed remain the same.

Lets say you have your `class Person`:

```
class Person {
    var title: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var surname: String = ""
}
```

You can add an array of `Person` in your ViewController.
This array is bound to your tableView datasource and therefore the `Person` instances within it are displayed in your TableView

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var personArray: [Person] = []

    // MARK:- TableViewDelegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return personArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.person = personArray[indexPath.row] // - 1
        return cell
    }
}
```

As you can notice, the cell now contains a new reference `person` to the associated person you want to display/edit. 
See `CustomCell` implementation below :

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    weak var person: Person? { // the reference to the associated person
        didSet {
            // when Person is set, we update the fields 
            titleTextField.text = person?.title ?? ""
            nameTextField.text = person?.name ?? ""
            surnameTextField.text = person?.surname ?? ""
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var surnameTextField: UITextField!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Add action when textField text change 
        titleTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
        nameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
        surnameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    @objc func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){

        // switch on the textField to see which info should be edited 
        switch textField {
            case titleTextField:
                person?.title = titleTextField.text ?? ""
            case nameTextField:
                person?.name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
            case surnameTextField:
                person?.surname = surnameTextField.text ?? ""
            default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Doing so, your modification of `Person` are handled in the associated `CustomCell`. 
When the tableview is reloaded, it will keep the datas that you already entered
When you edit the TextField, it will change the `person` and considering it is a reference, you will see the difference in your `personArray` on the main VC

---

Once again it is not copy/pastable and should be considered as **pseudo-code**

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, I found out how you can get the selected row in a custom cell table view:

```
- (IBAction)name:(id)sender {
    NSInteger num = [_viewTableView selectedRow];
    NSLog(@"thisTable selectedRow %ld", (long)num);
}
```